# how to reset a nameref in bash

Tags: bash, indirection

Let's say I have something like this with bash

```
func ()
{
   local -n ref
   ...
   ref="somevar"
   ref="somevalue"
   ...
   ref="someothervar"
}
```

So, `ref` is a nameref bash style. With the first assignment to it the var (`somevar`) to be modified through `ref` is set. With the second assignment to `ref` the var `somevar` is modified. Then let's say that I wanted to use `ref` to modify another var `someothervar`. Obviously doing just what you see in the third assignment to `ref` does not work, since bash thinks we are still modifying `somevar` through `ref` and so the string `someothervar` is assigned to `somevar`.

The only way I found to "reset" the var referenced by `ref` is by doing this

```
func ()
{
   local -n ref
   ...
   ref="somevar"
   ref="somevalue"
   ...
   unset -n ref
   local -n ref
   ref="someothervar"
}
```

That is, by first unsetting `ref` with `unset -n` (notice the `-n`) and then re-declaring it.

I think there should be a less cumbersome way of doing this, ideally with a specific syntax variation for an assignment to `ref` meant to reset its referred variable.
But I wasn't able to find anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Say `local -n ref="someothervar"` without unsetting `ref`.

Comment: Yes, that saves a line but I was hoping for something that doesn't mess with the scoping as a `local` declaration does. Let's say I want to pass the name of `ref` to another function `func2` called by `func`. If `func2` needs to reset the indirection of `ref` it can't use a `local` declaration because the "new" `ref` would then be only within the scope of `func2`.

Comment: Then you may instead want to use `declare -n ref=...`.

Comment: Nameref is not the only type of indirection in Bash. To change a variable in the calling function, use `local -g` without a nameref. You can declare a nameref based on it later (or the old good exclamation mark still works). Here, for example, `f2` changes `f1`’s `v` to point at `v2` instead of `v1`, without touching the global `v` which keeps pointing at `v3`. Not a nameref, but it does the job: `v1=a; v2=b; v3=c; v=v3; f1() { local v=v1; echo "${v}=${!v}"; f2; echo "${v}=${!v}"; }; f2() { local -g v; v=v2; }; f1; echo "${v}=${!v}";`

Comment: FYI, in case you want multiple levels of indirection, namerefs in Bash have a bug (or a well-known limitation, diplomatically said) that restricts them [to eight levels](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-04/msg00186.html). (See `Repeat-By:` in the post.) “Old style” exclamation marks have no such limitations \o/, but they need cycles for multiple “hops” /o\. The only case where namerefs are necessary are array references, due to the fact that `${!array[@]}` expands to indices. Exclamation marks still work fine the other way round though, as in `b=blah; a[2]=b; echo "${!a[2]}";`.